# cssnext から rem に自動で px を加える機能をなくしたい

Tags: css, gulp, postcss

cssnextを使っているのですが、IE8のサポートが切れたのでremに自動にpxを加える機能をなくしたいのですが、セットになっているので、これだけ外すことはできないのでしょうか？

https://github.com/robwierzbowski/node-pixrem
を見ても英語で完全にはわからず翻訳してもそれらしい記述が見つかりません。

どなたか、ご存じないでしょうか？
初心者にもわかるように解説してくれる方お願いします。

テラテイルで聞いていたのですが、回答がないのでこちらで聞くことにしました。

Comment: cssnextだけにすればよいということでよろしいでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございました。
cssnextを削除してcssnextWithoutRemのみ残してみます。

Comment: できたようです。
ありがとうございました。
gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  // cssnext,                      //一旦空の配列を作成
  cssnextWithoutRem, //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  customProperties,
  customMedia
  ];
でうまくいきましたが、
cssnextWithoutRemとはcssnextと同じプラグインがほぼ入っているが
remをpxにする機能だけ外しているのでこちらだけプラグインとして使えばほかのcssnext機能は問題なく使えるという認識でよろしいでしょうか

Comment: 解決なさったようで、よかったですね。typo 的な部分は除き、質問を整理させていただきました。コメントも削除しています（このコメントも後で削除すると思います）。今後はマルチポスト先は URL も含めて紹介するのがよいと思います。（ただ、URL を含めたとしても、マルチポスト先の記述を前提とした質問文にはしないで下さい。Stack Overflow の場合は独立して理解できる質問にしていただく必要があります）

Comment: テラテイルは削除ができないので、そのようになった次第です。
削除できればするのですが、向こうで聞いて、ずっと回答がないとどうしてもこの形になってしまいます。

Comment: 最後にcssnextWithoutRemとはcssnextと同じプラグインがほぼ入っているが remをpxにする機能だけ外しているのでこちらだけプラグインとして使えばほかのcssnext機能は問題なく使えるという認‌​識でよろしいでしょうかだけ教えてもらえませんか

Comment: マルチポスト先を削除する必要はないと思いますし、たぶん削除しない方がよいと思います。私が申し上げたのは、URL も記載した方がよい、という事だけです。また、これは私の考えに過ぎず、規則があるわけではないです。

Comment: `cssnextWithoutRem` についてはご理解の通りです。ただ、`cssnextWithoutRem` という変数名は、たまたま私が回答で用いただけですから、好きに変更して構いませんし、回答の冒頭のコードのように、変数に代入せずに用いても構いません。（ここらへんは `gulpfile.js` が JavaScript のプログラムである事から、JavaScript が解らないと、理解が難しい部分かもしれません）

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございました。これにて

Comment: StackOverflow では解決済みの質問に新たな問いを追加してはいけません。

Comment: 了解しました。別質問にします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

端的には下記のようになります。

```
postcss([
    cssnext({
        features: {
            rem: false
        }
    })
])
```

---

（例示コードは Gulp での利用を想定しています）

cssnext の話なので、まずは [cssnext のドキュメント](http://cssnext.io/usage/)をあたるのがよいです。
`browsers` オプションの利用が推奨されていますが、これを使うにはまず [Browserslist](https://github.com/ai/browserslist) について理解する必要がありますから、今回は `features` を指定する方法を示します。

cssnext をカスタマイズなしに使う場合は通常、`require('postcss-cssnext')` の戻り値をそのまま `postcss` に渡しますが、これは呼び出し可能な関数になっており、オプションを指定するオブジェクトを渡して呼び出す事で、カスタマイズされたプロセッサが作られます。

```
const cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
const cssnextWithoutRem = cssnext({
    features: {
        rem: false,
    },
});
```

冗長ですが上のように書くと、変数 `cssnextWithoutRem` に `rem` の機能が無効化されたプロセッサが代入されます。
素の `cssnext` の代りに、このプロセッサを `postcss` に渡すプラグインとして使います。
上の冗長な書き方に従い `gulpfile.js` を記述すると、例えば下記のようになります。

```
// gulpfile.js
// src -> dest

const gulp = require("gulp");
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

const cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
const cssnextWithoutRem = cssnext({
    features: {
        rem: false,
    },
});

const cssPlugins = [
    cssnextWithoutRem,
];

gulp.task("css", function(){
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(cssPlugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/'));
});

gulp.task("default", ["css"]);
```