# autoprefixerを導入したのですが、エラーが出ます。

Tags: gulp

http://blog.shibayu36.org/entry/2016/07/20/102641
を参考にautoprefixerを導入したのですが、エラーが出ます。
おそらく

```
  autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],
          cascade: false
      }),
```

が間違っているのだと思いますが、JS初心者にもわかるように教えていただければ幸いです。

・エラー

```
[14:56:23] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\gulpfile.js
[14:56:23] Starting 'watch'...
[14:56:23] Finished 'watch' after 246 ms
[14:57:09] Starting 'css'...
[14:57:09] 'css' errored after 421 μs
[14:57:09] ReferenceError: autoprefixer is not defined
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\gulpfile.js:21:3)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\gulp\index.js:36:18)
    at Gaze.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\glob-watcher\index.js:18:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Gaze.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Gaze.emit (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\gaze\lib\gaze.js:129:32)
    at C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\lll\node_modules\gaze\lib\gaze.js:415:16
    at StatWatcher._pollers.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\lllll\Desktop\images\gulp-folder\website\log\node_modules\gaze\lib\gaze.js:326:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at StatWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at StatWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1487:10)
```

・ソース

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); //gulpをインポート
var postcssimport = require('postcss-import');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss'); //gulp-postcssをインポート
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext'); //cssnextをインポート
var cssnextWithoutRem = cssnext({
    features: {
        rem: false,
    },
}); //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var calc = require('postcss-calc');
var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える

gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssnextWithoutRem, //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
  autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],
          cascade: false
      }),
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  customProperties,
  customMedia
  ];

console.log( Array.isArray(plugins) );//pluginsの定義の後で、 !Array.isArray(plugins)の値がどうなってるかをログを取る為

  return gulp.src(
    ['./src-before/*' , './src-before/*/*'],
    { base: 'src-before' })         //src-before下にある.cssファイルを指定
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/css'));          //生成されたCSSをdest-after下に配置
});

//以下gulp-watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(['src-before/*' , 'src-before/*/*' , 'src-before/*/*/*'], ['css']);//監視したいファイルの相対パス
});



var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
```

としたところトランスパイルはできました。

ただ、nextcssにこれはあるようなので下記のエラーが出ます。

> Warning: postcss-cssnext found a duplicate plugin ('autoprefixer') in
>   your postcss plugins. This might be inefficient. You should remove
>   'autoprefixer' from your postcss plugin list since it's already
>   included by postcss-cssnext.

結局下記をnextcssで行うためにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか？

```
autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],
      cascade: false
  }),
```

・教えてもらった情報をもとに自分で試行錯誤しましたがエラーが出ます。

```
//gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp'); //gulpをインポート
var postcssimport = require('postcss-import');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss'); //gulp-postcssをインポート
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext'); //cssnextをインポート
var cssNext = cssnext({
    browsers: [
        'last 2 version', 
        'iOS >= 8.1',
        'Android >= 4.4'
    ],
}); //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var calc = require('postcss-calc');
var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える


gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssNext, //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
  autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],
          cascade: false
      }),
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  customProperties,
  customMedia
  ];

console.log( Array.isArray(plugins) );//pluginsの定義の後で、 !Array.isArray(plugins)の値がどうなってるかをログを取る為

  return gulp.src(
    ['./src-before/*' , './src-before/*/*'],
    { base: 'src-before' })         //src-before下にある.cssファイルを指定
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/css'));          //生成されたCSSをdest-after下に配置
});

//以下gulp-watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch(['src-before/*' , 'src-before/*/*' , 'src-before/*/*/*'], ['css']);//監視したいファイルの相対パス
});
```

下記の部分は読み込んだプラグインを記載するようですが、autoprefixerは
プラグインの中の機能を記載しているのでしょうか？
初心者なのでここまで難しいとわかりません。

```
gulp.task('css', function () {           //”css”タスクを登録
  var plugins = [
  postcssimport,
  cssNext, //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
  autoprefixer({
          browsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],
          cascade: false
      }),
  nested,
  calc,
  csswring,
  customProperties,
  customMedia
  ];
```

その後下記のようにrequireを使った書き方をしていたので、そのように自分なりに行ったのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
最後にここだけ教えてもらえませんか？

```
 const plugins = [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require(cssnext({
          browsers: [
            'last 2 version',
            'iOS >= 8.1',
            'Android >= 4.4',
          ],
        })), //ソースではわからないが、IE9以上は、remが使えるので、remからpxを生成されないように、こちらで行っている
        require('csswring')
    ];
```

Comment: 質問のエラーの原因とは関係ありませんが、`autoprefixer` は [`cssnext` に含まれています](http://cssnext.io/features/#automatic-vendor-prefixes)。他にも `postcss-calc`、`postcss-custom-properties`、`postcss-custom-media` が `cssnext` に含まれています。また、`postcss-nested` は `cssnext` に含まれる `postcss-nesting` と機能的に重複しています。これらのプラグインは `cssnext` を使うのなら必要ないはずです。

Comment: 「`autoprefixer` モジュールを使う際に `autoprefixer is not defined` というエラーが出るのをどうすればよいか？」という質問に対して[完全な回答](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/31570/3054)が既にあります。「`autoprefixer` モジュールを直接に使うのは止めた。ついては、`cssnext` に含まれる `autoprefixer` にオプションを渡したいが、どうすればよいか？」という新たな問いを投入しないで下さい。

Comment: 繰り返し繰り返し、同じ方に同じ事を指摘するのは心苦しいのですが StackOverflow の使い方をご理解いただきたいと思っています。納得いかれないのでしたら、[Meta の方](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/)でご意見下さい。

Comment: それでは、新しくcssnext に含まれる autoprefixer にオプションを渡したいが、どうすればよいか？」という新たな問いの質問を作れということですか？

Comment: 私はそうするべきだと思います。ただ、私が拘り過ぎなのかも知れませんし、@web さんがもう放っておいて欲しいとおっしゃるなら、そのように致します。

Comment: 中途半端な状況で終了すると、後で見に来た人が結局解決できずに、その方が迷惑かなとおもったのですが、ほかの方もそう思うのなら別質問にしても構いません

Comment: 他の方の意見も聞きたい、という事でしたら [meta](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/) で質問なさるのがよいです。私が過去に @web さんの質問に回答した経験からいうと、@web さんがエラーに遭遇する度に、同じ質問に次々と投入される問い（作業ログ）をまとめ上げて一つの Q&A として完成させられる回答者はいないと思います。あまりしつこくするのは本意ではないので、私の意見はこれ位にします。

Comment: 兄弟サイトのようなものがあるのですね。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta
を見てみましたが、いまいちこことの違いがわからないのですが、こちらで質問をすれば、解決するまで質問を続けても良いのですね。もしそうならその方が利便性が良いので始めからこちらに質問します。

Comment: すいません Meta はそういう場所ではないです。「ほかの方もそう思うのな‌​ら」とおしゃったので、「他の方の意見も聞きたい、という事でしたら」という意味でご紹介しました。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta をご覧下さい。

Comment: ちゃんと議論をしたいのであればmetaを使うべきですね。読み込んでいないからエラーが出て実行できない、と重複していて警告が出る、別の問題です。私はトピックへの質問に答えましたが、編集によってまるで見当違いのようになってますよね。質問のパターンによっては仕方ない場合もありますが、繰り返してややこしくなりかねません。

Comment: 始めの質問はこちらでして、その後のコメントでのさらなる追求や疑問点の解決はmetaで行うのが正しいということでしょうか？
それとも、このサイトの議論のみmetaで扱えということでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoprefixer` を`reuire`してないため、ですね。

PostCSSのプラグインとして autoprefixer を使うのであれば gulp-autoprefixer ではなく [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)の方になるかと思います。

各requireの最後あたりに

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
```

を追加します。

---

#### 追記された質問について

(ここで回答するのは少し気が引けますが……)

質問に記載された

```js
var cssnextWithoutRem = cssnext({
    features: {
        rem: false,
    },
}); //IE9以上は、remが使えるので、pxを生成されないようにする
```

の箇所ですが、ここにcssnextのオプションを指定します。

[Using postcss-cssnext](http://cssnext.io/usage/)

指定の仕方はautoprefixerと同じはずです。

```
var cssnextWithoutRem = cssnext({
    browsers: [
        'last 2 version', 
        'iOS >= 8.1',
        'Android >= 4.4'
    ],
    features: {
        rem: false,
    },
});
```

そもそもbrowsersとfeaturesは重複する(この指定だとremはoffになるはず)ので`features`の指定は省略できます。

```
var cssNext = cssnext({
    browsers: [
        'last 2 version', 
        'iOS >= 8.1',
        'Android >= 4.4'
    ],
});
```

これは前回の質問( [cssnext から rem に自動で px を加える機能をなくしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31539/2376) )でも触れられてたことですね。

---

上記を踏まえて、提示されたgulpfileを書き換えるとこうなります。

```js
//gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp'); //gulpをインポート
var postcssimport = require('postcss-import');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss'); //gulp-postcssをインポート
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext'); //cssnextをインポート
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var calc = require('postcss-calc');
var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える


gulp.task('css', function () {
  var plugins = [
    postcssimport,
    cssnext({
      browsers: [
        'last 2 version', 
        'iOS >= 8.1',
        'Android >= 4.4',
      ],
    }),
    nested,
    calc,
    csswring,
    customProperties,
    customMedia
  ];

  console.log( Array.isArray(plugins) );//pluginsの定義の後で、 !Array.isArray(plugins)の値がどうなってるかをログを取る為

  return gulp.src(
    ['./src-before/*' , './src-before/*/*'],
    { base: 'src-before' })         //src-before下にある.cssファイルを指定
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))              //PostCSSにファイルを処理してもらう
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest-after/css'));          //生成されたCSSをdest-after下に配置
});
// 以下省略
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
re('postcss-calc');
var customProperties = require("postcss-custom-properties");
var customMedia = require("postcss-custom-media"); //うまくいっていない。カスタムメディアクエリーズが使える
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
としたところトランスパイルはできました。

Warning: postcss-cssnext found a duplicate plugin ('autoprefixer') in your postcss plugins. This might be inefficient. You should remove 'autoprefixer' from your postcss plugin list since it's already included by postcss-cssnext.

Comment: @mjyさんがコメントで指摘されているように、cssnextにautoprefixerが含まれてあるのでその重複を示す警告です。言い換えれば、当該の行を書き足す必要はなかった、ということです。

Comment: var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');が必要なかったということはわかりますがbrowsers: ['last 2 version', 'iOS >= 8.1', 'Android >= 4.4'],はどこに書くのでしょうか

Comment: 結局不要なことをやったわけなので、結局どうすればよいか回答してもらえませんか

Comment: @web 追記しました。確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
最後に記載してもらった
var cssNext = cssnext({
の方だけを記載すれば、remからPXの機能はOFFにできると考えてよいのでしょうか？
rem: false,
を削除しても、

Comment: はずです。確認はしてませんが。(ところで変数名を変えているので注意してくださいね。)

Comment: autoprefixerに関する記述を直接する必要はありません。(全体を追記で貼りますね。)

Comment: ありがとうございました。
エラーが出なくなり確かにPXも消えたようです。
ただプレフィックスがどうなっているか確かめる方法が大変ですね。
caniuseでちょうどそれ前後の物を見つけてそれがどうなっているか確認するしかないのですかね？

Comment: ソースがあるので質問欄に追記をさせてもらいました。
何度もすいませんが最後にこれだけお願いします。

Comment: 意味をわからずにrequireで置き換えるのに問題があるのでは?requireをプラグイン定義内に統一したいのであれば `require('postcss-cssnext')({...})` といった書き方になりますがあまりきれいとはいいにくいですね。

Comment: require('postcss-cssnext')({
      browsers: [
        'last 2 version',
        'iOS >= 8.1',
        'Android >= 4.4',
      ],
    }),
でできたようです対応ブラウザの確認方法がないのですが